# HBase: GET request for row data with timestamp

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, hbase, http-get

I created a HBase table via Java API and added data via a Put. I can also read the data in Java with a corresponding Get. The HBase documentation says that a cell value also can be read by using a GET request e.g. in browser, see [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest).

The following request works for me, which returns the whole row:

```
http://my_hbase_url:12345/dm-table/exampleRow/family:html?v=1
```

The result is an xml and looks following:

```
<CellSet>
  <Row key="ZXhhbXBsZVJvdw==">
    <Cell column="ZmFtaWx5Omh0bWw=" timestamp="1466667016879">PGh0bWw+Li4uTXkgSFRNTC4uLjwvaHRtbD4=</Cell>
  </Row>
</CellSet>
```

If you have a look at the timestamp it is `1466667016879`, but when I call

```
http://my_hbase_url:12345/dm-table/exampleRow/family:html/1466667016879
```

I get a `not found` result! Also the Java code works and gives me this timestamp:

```
HTable table = new HTable(config, TABLE_NAME.getBytes());

Get g = new Get("exampleRow".getBytes());
g.setTimeStamp(1466667016879L);

Result r = table.get(g);
System.out.println("Timestamp: " + r.rawCells()[0].getTimestamp());

byte[] value = r.getValue(CF_DEFAULT.getBytes(), "html".getBytes());
String valueStr = new String(value);
System.out.println("GET: " + valueStr);
```

this prints:

```
Timestamp: 1466667016879
GET: <html>...My HTML...</html>
```

So timestamp does exist, but the http GET request won't work with the timestamp, can someone help?

Comment: I looked into it but I can't use `family:html`. Is it for HBase 2.0 only?

Comment: The column-familiy "family" and the column "html" are just from my table example, I created the table with this structure. I use HDP 2.4 with HBase 1.1.2

Comment: I am dumb :/... I get to download a file instead of having a nice Xml answer. WIll try to look into it again

Comment: okay, reproduced the same error, maybe there is a JIRA about it. What is your HBase version?

Comment: This is definitly a bug, try a put on the same row/column, and query the current timestamp. Do you also get the previous data and not the current?

Comment: Ok, thank you for trying out. The HBase Version is 1.1.2. I also get a file download instead of a xml sometimes, restarting the HBase REST service helped me... The timestamp thing will I try next week and give feedback, didn't try to update a dataset yet.

Comment: I will try some other things to understand the behavior, will keep you posted. Got the same version so maybe this is fixed in 2.0

Comment: okay, first and last update: the command sends back the last element insert strictly before the timestamp given. Try putting timestamp +1 and you will have the right value. This is quite stupid and need a fix

Comment: (I am trying to fill a jira ticket but I am a noob at it so I am not sure how to do that properly, will keep you updated)

Comment: @Whitefret You are right! When I use (timestamp + 1) in the url I get the correct result. I will post this as answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp in the URL looks for the newest data set with an EARLIER timestamp!

So have a look at following example:

When you call e.g. `http://my_hbase_url:12345/dm-table/exampleRow/family:html` you get the following result:

```
<CellSet>
  <Row key="ZXhhbXBsZVJvdw==">
    <Cell column="ZmFtaWx5Omh0bWw=" timestamp="1466667016879">PGh0bWw+Li4uTXkgSFRNTC4uLjwvaHRtbD4=</Cell>
  </Row>
</CellSet>
```

So if you want to get this result via timestamp (e.g. because you have different versions of the data saved), you can add the timestamp to the URL to get the latest dataset with an earlier timestamp. So, to get the data-set shown above you have to add `/<timestamp + 1>` to the URL:

```
http://my_hbase_url:12345/dm-table/exampleRow/family:html/1466667016880
```

This brings the same result as shown above. If this is the only or earliest version, calling `http://my_hbase_url:12345/dm-table/exampleRow/family:html/1466667016879` wouldn't find any result and would end in a `not found` result, as described in the question above.

However, you have to use `<timestamp + 1>` (or higher) to get the expected data!

Thank you @Whitefret for this solving hint!

Comment: here is the jira link, the first comment explain the behavior. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-16106